# Can we create two objects of same name in a java class

Tags: java, class, methods, scope

```
public class Main {
    void sum(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println((a + b));
        Main ob = new Main();
        ob.difference(200, 100);
    }

    void difference(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println((a - b));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Main ob = new Main();
        ob.sum(100, 25);

    }
}
```

When I create objects of same name in the main method, compiler is throwing error but when I create objects with same name in different methods it is getting compiled. Why is it so?

Comment: Variables have a scope. A variable declared in a method is *local* to that method. The same name can be used in different scopes without any problem. It's for the same reason that you cannot use a variable declared in a method from another method.

Comment: In laymen terms, scope is basically what falls in every set of `{ }`. Whatever you write in every separate one of these is a separate variable and won't collide with each other. But when, you create two of the same name in a single scope or parent child scope then this happens.

Comment: " compiler is throwing error" - that error is important. include it in your question !

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse the reference to make the variable point to a new object like below.
In this case, you don't have to declare the type again. It will always be the same type for the same variable, that's how statically-typed languages work.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Main ob = new Main(1);
    ob.sum(100, 25);

    ob = new Main(2);
    ob.sum(100, 25);
}
```

Comment: I'm answering the question "When I create objects of same name in the main method, compiler is throwing error... Why?"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `@ernest_k` is right on point.. but I am not sure why you need another object inside `add` method, methods of inside a class can call each other without an object, since `Main` was a static method while `add` and `subtract` are not, you needed an object inside your main method.

You can have one single object inside `main` and `add` will be called using that which in turn `difference`.

Note: You can also make `add` and `difference` as `static` so you do not need any object at all.